# Fresh XCode install shows revoked certificates

Tags: xcode

First of all, I am a total Mac novice.
I have been getting "unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Distribution..." when trying to make an AppStore build in Visual Studio 2019 (AdHoc and Development builds work fine), and after trying everything I could find to solve the situation, I decided to delete all my certificates, provisioning profiles, and even XCode from my Mac and start completely over.
After a fresh install of XCode from the AppStore, I added my AppleID to XCode and it somehow can still see a certificate that was revoked last week. It is a certificate I created last week in attempt to resolve my issue, but I later revoked it.
Somehow, XCode still thinks it's there, but if I right-click and select Delete Certificate, I get a Write Permissions Error.
[image]

XCode must keep a list of certificates somewhere that persists even if XCode is deleted and reinstalled, but I can't find it.
So I have two questions: How do I get rid of this certificate reference in XCode? and
What does "unable to build chain to self-signed root" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I did not know that certificates were shown in more than one place in KeyChain.

Comment: Yep. Even though I delete them from Keychain, they still show up in XCode Accounts.